# How to do manager MIB parsing with SharpSNMP

Tags: c#, sharp-snmp

I just want my C# .NET manager code to be able to do SNMP V2 sets and gets using the variable and table names defined in the MIB and not have to use the long OID numeric string to make the code easier to read and maintain.  I am not developing a custom agent.

Is there a way to do this with the SharpSNMP library?  I know that there is also a Sharp SNMP MIB compiler pro, but its not obvious to me if that is only for agent creation or if it can also be used with the manager software to parse the MIB file and understand the interface.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid, that  functions you are looking for are implemented in Pro version of this library http://pro.sharpsnmp.com/en/latest/getting-started/assembly-features.html#name-oid-translation

Comment: Thanks, a confirmation of that suspicion is just what I was looking for.